# Golang migration stuck with no error message in Codebuild

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-codebuild, golang-migrate

When running golang migrate command, Golang migration stuck with no error message in AWS Codebuild. I am using RDS ( Aurora PostgreSQL 13.9). Do you have similar issues? I added

```
 -verbose
```

flag but it's showing: start buffering... and then it just stuck.

What I tried:

- use latest version of golang migrate
- add a -verbose flag

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, but on VPS, also stuck on buffering. Locally the migration happens instantly. On VPS it takes 10 minutes for an almost empty database. So, the answer is to just wait. I thought it freezes and spend yesterday evening and most of today trying to figure out what goes wrong, I then got distracted and let the thing run and 11 minutes later the migration was successful.